# Using EM (Expectation Maximization) algorithm for Training Logistic Regression

Tags: machine-learning, classification, statistics, logistic-regression, expectation-maximization

Is it possible to learn the weights for a logistic regression classifier using EM (Expectation Maximization)algorithm? Is there any instance reference?

Answer (score 2):

Use [Algorithm 1](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.0040.pdf) from this paper. The rest of paper is more about the analysis of algorithm and theoretical background which is very nice but not necessary for your purpose. Implementation of the algorithm in Python or R is pretty straightforward.

Hope it helps :)